# Gesture recognizer for UIView no longer working after connecting the view to IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a custom button which is basically a UIView with a gesture recognizer. Both the UIView and it's gesture recognizer were put together in interface builder.

The action for the gesture recognizer triggers a segue and opens a view controller. This works just fine.

I created an IBOutlet for this UIView button, but it seems that when I hook it up the action of triggering the segue and opening the next view controller stops working, even though the gesture recognizer and action are still showing up in interface builder.

Why does the gesture recognizer stop working when I hook the UIView up to an IBOutlet?

Comment: Is it possible that your gesture recognizer's target/action changed after you set up the view outlet?

Comment: @featherless Nope. I just double checked to be sure but the connections are all intact.

Comment: why you add gesture in your UIView?
Simple make your UIView to UIControl class from storyboard and you can simple add action on it using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Check that the User Interaction is enabled for that view in the id-inspector or not. Or check there are no extra connection are shown in the connection inspector

Answer (score 0):

Why you add gesture in your UIView? Simple make your UIView to UIControl class from storyboard and you can simple add action like button on it using storyboard

[image]

Or by adding gesture you can do it

connect IBOutlet of your view with UIView

then add gesture in it

[image]

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //The setup code (in viewDidLoad in your view controller)
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [vw_button addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

    //Do stuff here...
}
```